# How to solve flutter gradle build error?C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 991

Tags: flutter, build.gradle

I am trying to run my app but every time it's showing this error. can you please tell me what is the problem here?

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 991
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

PS C:\Users\sadma\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\Eattly> flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.26.0-17.3.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1379], locale en-ZW)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2) [√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.53.2)
[√] Connected device (1 available) • No issues found!

Comment: Can you add full error message from the output?

Comment: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 991

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 26s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

Comment: Can you run `flutter doctor` and put its output to the question?

Comment: PS C:\Users\sadma\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\Eattly> flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, 1.26.0-17.3.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version
    10.0.18363.1379], locale en-ZW)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.53.2)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!

Comment: Please add `flutter doctor` output to the question. You can edit question by click on "Edit" button.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest deleting the gradle file and running flutter create which will replace all missing files, so the bad script in gradle folder/file will be replaced with the original one

Comment: it says flutter create command needs a directory